# Very simple question regarding JQuery submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I would like to accomplish form submit on reload.

So I have the following code:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
     $(window).unbind("beforeunload");
});

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
     $('#disconnectform').submit();
});
```

Basically, I want the disconenctform only submitted on reload, not on submit.  However,  `$('#disconnectform').submit()` doesn't seem to work form.  Any ideas why?  How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Binding an event handler to window.unload to submit a form seems a bit hacky.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker I basically want to alert the server to disvalidate the session when user reloads or quits the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On reload, the browser does not maintain session data. By consequence, when you hit refresh, the data in the form may not be saved. Most browsers will give you a "form resubmission" warning when this is attempted. Some browsers do not handle this situation at all.

This does not answer your question, because I believe that you need to re-think your design.

Good luck

-tjw

Answer (score 0):

If you really WANT to achieve this, use jquery cookie plugin. Then on page load run the function if a cookie is set. :)

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/1386/release